# How can I change directory in Ubuntu distrubution 16.04

Tags: docker, nginx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztap0.png)

I am trying to change directory in Ubuntu distrubution . cd is not working .How can I change?

Comment: dockerfile is not a directory it is a file

Answer (score 1):

The files you're trying to cd into aren't directories - they're files. The errors look like cd is working fine. You can try an `ls -l` to confirm that those are files vs. directories, it's not clear from your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward in all queries, post all relevant data and the explain about the issue clearly. This will help in faster resolution.

Coming to your current issue: Your docker build failed stating that it failed to fetch nginx related package.

Also, `touch` command creates files if they do not exist (updates timestamp if exists) and you can only `cd` into directories

Share the contents of Dockerfile you're using so that the issue can be identified.